# Not able to import antd stylesheet, Error while importing antd stylesheet , gives webpack errors

Tags: css, webpack, error-handling, antd, webpack-style-loader

When I import

`import 'antd/dist/antd.css';`

these lines I got error like below.

```
Compiled with problems:X

Error:

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently 
no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

| /* stylelint-disable */

| /* stylelint-disable declaration-bang-space-before,no-duplicate-selectors,string-no-newline */

**>  [class^=ant-]::-ms-clear,**

| [class*= ant-]::-ms-clear,

| [class^=ant-] input::-ms-clear,
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It will be easier for people to help you if you can edit your question to include the CSS you are having trouble with and show what you've tried - especially if you can narrow it down to just the bit where you are having the problem. You might find reviewing these guidelines to be helpful: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I am building a react app using webpack, i wanted antd to be used for it,but while importing its stylesheet i got this error

Comment: were you able to fix it?